# Chrome icon replaced by New Tab - Google Chrome

Tags: 13.10, launcher, icons, google-chrome, chromebook

I'm new to Ubuntu, just installed it on my ChromeBook a few days ago. So please forgive me.

My problem is with Google Chrome. I have it installed and working, but when I open it and start browsing, a new icon appears in the launcher titled "New Tab - Google Chrome", which replaces the original Chrome icon. When I click this new icon, it turns yellow and does nothing. I have rebooted the computer and reinstalled Chrome, no fix. I can still open Chrome from the terminal though. I would like to have an icon in the launcher that opens Chrome.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was fixed by answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377851/ubuntu-13-10-google-account-google-chrome-icon-issue 

Don't know exactly why it happened, but I think it was after I setup Ubuntu Online Account / Google Account.

Comment: screenshot please

Answer (score 0):

They way I was able to fix this problem was to follow the instructions in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/413263)!.