# Ubuntu 13.10 (Google Account - Google Chrome) Icon Issue

Tags: permissions, google-chrome

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10. I went to the Google Chrome website using default Firefox, downloaded 64 bit chrome, went through the process of the software center, and opened Chrome.

However, every time I open the *Google Chrome* icon on the Launcher, it just glows yellow while a different icon called *Google Accounts - Google Chrome* opens.

How do I get rid of this *Google Accounts* icon and just let the original Google Chrome open ?

Executing `gedit google-chrome.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` yielded:

```
*(gedit:2454): WARNING**: Could not load Gedit repository : Typelib fil for namespace 'GTKsource' version 3.0 not found.
```

When I executed `gedit google-chrome.desktop` in Terminal, the gedit page was *empty* (it did not display any contents for the `google-chrome.desktop` file).

How to fix these ?

EDIT 2: Executing `google-chrome` from terminal opens the regular Google Chrome, but it runs from terminal (meaning that if I end the Terminal session, I end the Chrome session as well).

Comment: do `ls /usr/share/applications`. Find the `google-chrome.desktop`, or something related to google chrome. Open the terminal and type `gedit ThatName.desktop` and post the contents of that file here.

Comment: Hello There! I did what you said to do and this is what I got:*(gedit:2454): WARNING**: Could not load Gedit repository : Typelib fil for namespace 'GTKsource' version 3.0 not found. When I did Getid google-chrome.desktop, the gedit page was empty. I tried again and I got the same message but the only thing that changed was (gedit:3289) the second time around.

Comment: what was the output of `ls /usr/share/applications`? Does it contain google chrome related file?

Comment: Yes, there is a file called "google-chome.desktop" in the list when I execute that command.

Comment: Open that file and add the contents of file in your question. I am not sure if the problem is really in that file, but I guess it is. And also try `google-chrome` in terminal and tell us what happens.

Comment: When opening the file with Gedit, the page is empty, showing no contents of the file. When trying google-chrome from terminal, it shows a Google Chrome icon, but actually opens up a "Google Accounts - Google Chrome" icon on Launchpad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome opens in a new window in a new launcher icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396448/google-chrome-opens-in-a-new-window-in-a-new-launcher-icon)

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal run :

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

If the resulting *Gedit* is empty, add following lines to it (Copy and Paste):

If it is not empty, edit the available content in it to become as following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=
Name=Google Chrome
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=google-chrome %F
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=google-chrome
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupWMClass=google-chrome
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;
X-AppInstall-Package=google-chrome

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=google-chrome
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Desktop Action Incognito]
Name=Open a New Window in incognito mode
Exec=google-chrome --incognito
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Desktop Action TempProfile]
Name=Open a New Window with a temporary profile
Exec=google-chrome --temp-profile
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain what it does? And did you just take the text from your `Gedit` file for Google Chrome?

Comment: Thank you again, it worked. However I do have some questions: For one, what does changing from %U to %F do? Secondly, I got this message twice when I closed the Gedit window after I edited the file: `(gedit:3381): GtK -WARNING**: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: First thing, to change or write in system files you have to gain root previlege. To gain it you need to add `gksudo` infront the gedit command. when `%U` is used, only that user account can open the application. Sometimes there are situations even I did install the application, Ubuntu take it as root account and doesnt give me the chance to open it. This happens when there is only one user account there. When `%F` is used, any user can use this. So what I do is change it to `%F`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If I am the only user on the machine, should I change it back to `%U`? And could you please explain what the error message I received means?